# How to use variables in a JQuery call

Tags: jquery, variables

I am trying to

```
function doRow(rowNum)
{

 $.ajax({
   url: "z.html",
   cache: false,
   success: function(html){
   $('#result + rowNum + "'").append(html);
 }
});
```

This does not seem to work.

I also want to pass variables to data attribute when I get that far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
function doRow(rowNum)
{

 $.ajax({
   url: "z.html",
   cache: false,
   success: function(html){
   $('#result'+rowNum).append(html);
 }
});
```

Comment: Lol, np, happens to the best of us ;)

Comment: Happened to me, too.  It's the simple things!